# How to store a list of objects to a session in a springMVC web application

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I would like to store a List to a session so I can access it and add/remove/delete objects in a separate controller upon request. I currently have a Controller that is creating a List and outputting it to a JSON, which I am then accessing from a jsp page using AngularJS.

I have tried using `@SessionAttributes` by adding the List to a Model, but the List is not stored correctly. I am fairly new to SpringMVC so any suggestions/advice on where to look would be appreciated.

**My Controller creating my List:**

```
@RestController
@SessionAttributes({"URLparam", "usersList"})
public class ReportController {

  @RequestMapping(value="/events")
  public List<Appliance> getEvents(@ModelAttribute("URLparam")String userInput, ModelMap model){
    List<Appliance> events = new ArrayList<>();
    events = ProcessChoice.ofList(userInput);
    model.addAttribute("usersList", events);
    System.out.println(userInput);
    return events;
  }
}
```

**My Controller that I want to edit the existing list:**

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("usersList")
public class EditListController {

  @RequestMapping(value="/testing", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String makeChanges(@RequestAttribute("usersList") List<Appliance> usersList) {
    //make changes to list here
    for(Appliance p: usersList) {
        System.out.println(p.getName());
    }
    return "testing";
  }
}
```

As it stands the code throws: `error 400 -  Missing request attribute 'usersList' of type List`

I can see there is an option to add a collection<> to the model, but I am not sure how to then store it as it doesn't let me give it a name.

Comment: Why are you trying to store session variables and not using a database? Also, what if two people call that URL, do you overwrite the session variables?

Comment: I am still learning, I should be using a database to handle personalised lists? What do I need to look into to learn how to implement that?

Comment: I'm sure than the keywords of "CRUD" and "Spring MVC" would get you decent search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ReportController you are storing the list ("events") to the model under the key "usersList". The model acts as data that can be rendered in the view. This way it does not get stored to the Session.

Consider something like:
session.setAttribute("usersList", events); 
in ReportController and the corresponding session.getAttribute("usersList") in the EditListController.

You can also omit the @SessionAttributes-annotation is you do it this way. If you want to use those annotations, get familiar with their scope (where to put them and where to use them) and usage here: http://vmustafayev4en.blogspot.de/2012/10/power-of-springs-modelattribute-and.html and official api doc here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html and

However storing data in the session might seem a good idea, but is often the reason for high memory footprint of the app if there are many active sessions - just so you know.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know this, could you suggest a way that I could better handle customised lists created by a user?

Comment: sure, one way is to store to the database as suggested by cricket_007 in his comment. However explaining this would exceed the scope of the original question. Another way is to find concepts around it by answering the question: do I really need this in the session or do I just want to render it on one page (whenever it's shown) => flash scope or model might do. Also the source of this data might help: how expensive is it to recreate or retrieve that data instead of stuffing it in the session. Probably it's too early - just be aware that you _might_ on day run into probs

Comment: Also be aware that the session is gone after the server is killed / restarted or the user ends the session or it times out or the cookie is lost. So storing to db might actually be the thing you want.

Please consider to ask another question for that topic or try to find it on google / SO like this: https://www.google.de/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=sring+mvc+where+to+store+session+related+data&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=BdK2WMW6O6Oo8wfI95DICw#q=spring+mvc+database+example&*
I'd be glad if you consider to mark my answer as solution if you think it was answering the original question.